# Center navigation bar css

Tags: css, menu, center

I want to have my navigation bar in the middle of the page but I don't know what to do.
Here is my code.

CSS

```
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
li {
  float:left;
}
a {
  display:block;
  width:80px;
  background-color:#000000
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://kevril.site40.net/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/SuperKevril">Youtube</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can we see your html?

Comment: sorry if that's a little hard to read

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Centering block level elements is easy, just define a `width` and set `margin:0 auto;`, but what if you don’t know that fixed width? You could use `text-align:center;`, but that won’t work on `width:100%` block-level elements either… that will only work on text-level elements.

Defining explicit `width` and `height` should always be avoided wherever possible, as doing so will make the document a lot less future-proof, flexible and extensible. Suppose you have four items in your navigation menu. You can work out the `width` of these and use `margin:0 auto;` to center them. Adding a fifth will increase the width, meaning you’d need to alter the CSS, too. This is far from ideal, and more so with a CMS to power the site (a client can add pages, but perhaps can’t edit CSS).

However, there is a way to have a centered horizontal navigation without knowing an explicit width, and without adding CSS. It’s also remarkably easy. Try this:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/work/">Work</a></li>
  <li><a href="/clients/">Clients</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-width:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}
.nav li{
    display:inline;
}
.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
position: relative;
margin: auto;
```